# Hiding IP (SRV record?)

Tags: dns, minecraft, srv-record

I am using AMP (McMyAdmin3) as control panel for my minecraft and the servers are located at a secret address, except my bungeecord (proxy so multiple minecraft servers can be connected) ofcourse. Now I am trying to have a control panel for my admins, but I want them not to see the IP. 
I was thinking of an SRV record, but I am not sure if this even CAN work or HOW it even works.
(Well I have an idea of how it works but I don't know if I am correct)

So I have pointed my domain 'manage.mydomain.com' to the IP I want, I put cloudflare protection on it, so if they resolve the IP, they cannot see the real IP. However, with this done they cannot type in the URL bar 'manage.mydomain.com:[port]' because cloudflare does not allow you to do that, because of the protection. So I tried setting up an SRV record like this:

_mcmyadmin._tcp.manage **POINTS TO** SRV 0 0 [port] manage.mydomain.com

I waited for 2 days now, and it still did not work, so I am sure that is not the case.
Is there any way to make this work? Or is not even possible with domain stuff :p
Or is there another way to fix this?

Kind regards,
Runefist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DNS is the **public** phone book of the internet. Its purpose is to take a domain name and map it to an IP Address. It is simply not possible to put anything in DNS and keep it secret.

When you put an address into your browser the first thing it does is find out the IP address associated with it.

In order to use a SRV record the application that uses it needs to be written to use them. Unless you are writing the frontend yourself, there are very few applications that will use SRV records. You can't just put data in there and expect it to be used.

If your intention here is to provide extra security to your servers, this isn't going to do you a lot of good. If you look at your server logs you are already being probed just by being online. The addition of a domain name won't do much change that.

You will be far better off understanding and hardening the security of your server than hiding it and hoping that nobody finds it, because it is almost guaranteed that they will if they have the inclination to do so.

Answer (score 2):

Minecraft SRV records are `_minecraft._tcp`, you can't change the service name or the client won't be able to resolve it.

That being said, Michael B is right, what you're doing is implementing security by obscurity (which, as we all know, is no security). Instead, you should be using `iptables` to block all IPs except for the bungee from being able to reach the backend.